# Does magnet pull of google cardboard triggers click event in aframe?

Tags: google-cardboard, aframe

I don't have Google cardboard right now to test. I'm using **universal-controls** and **mouse-cursor**. Will pulling magnet on Google cardboard trigger click event? Here's my camera universal-controls and cursor

```
<a-entity camera="active:true;userHeight:1.8"
position="0 2.2 4" mouse-cursor
universal-controls="movementEnabled:false"></a-entity>
```

I'm using aframe v0.3.0 aframe extras v2.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will if you use the `cursor` component. The cursor component provides an implementation of Cardboard click (which are just screen taps) and emits the click/mouseenter/mouseleave events.

https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/components/cursor.html

Comment: Thank you for you reply. One more question. When i tested on old android phone, i was able to look top and bottom by moving phone, but could not move left or right by moving phone, moving sideways worked with touch. Is that the default behavior or problem with my phone.

Comment: If it's really old, I can imagine it being a problem...we usually recommend modern smartphones. Even then, we'd prefer devices with true VR support.

Comment: Its really old and does not even have gyroscope just accelerometer. Thanks for help

Comment: It seems the canvas element consumes the click event initiated by the magnet pull.